# Dependency Injection issue

Tags: php, global

I have read about dependency injection, i understood it well, now i got a little issue, i'm making an oop site structure which will contain a lot of classes (members,games,posts,etc..).
Since a lot of people told me it is not recommended to use global variables for this purposes i am getting this little issue. for example:

```
$mysql_connection = ...connection
$members = new Members($mysql_connection); //i need to implement posts and games 
$posts = new Posts($mysql_connection); //i need to implement members
$games = new Games($mysql_connection); //i need to implement members
```

The order of the classes was not so important when i was using global variables to pass through classes:

```
global $connection;
$connection = ...connection

global $members;
$members = new Members();

global $posts;
$posts = new Posts();

etc...
```

example of a class:

```
class Posts{

 function getMemberPosts($id){
    ...implementing the globals
    global $connection, $members;
    ...using the globals
 }

}
```

So my question is, how can i do the same thing without using globals? (doesn't have to be dependency injection..)

Comment: I don't understand where your problem is. You are correctly creating a connection and are injecting it into the new classes as you instantiate them. All good, no?

Comment: I fail to see, what the OP is trying to do too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to store and use the injected component as opposed to a global one.

```
class Posts{
    protected $dbconnection;

    public function __construct($dbconn){
       // save the injected dependency as a property
       $this->dbconnection = $dbconn;
    }

    public function getMemberPosts($id, $members){
       // also inject the members into the function call

       // do something cool with members to build a query

       // use object notation to use the dbconnection object
       $this->dbconnection->query($query);
    }

}
```